# Changing out the Range power cord

Tags: wiring

My Range cord 3 prong is only 14 years old and in excellent condition.
However, we are getting a new range and they insist we get a new (over priced) 3 prong for our new range. I do not like this as I believe it is just another scam to make money. THE CORD WE HAVE IS FINE i DO BELIEVE SOMETHING IS VERY FISHY HERE. House built before 1979 FYI.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! If you'll spend a moment taking the [tour], you'll note that this is a _Question_ and Answer forum, not a place to post a rant. Please feel free to [edit] your post to actually ask a question and I'm sure you'll get some good answers. As it stands, this isn't a Question, so it will likely get closed.

Comment: The only reason to change the cord is if it is damaged or the new range is higher power rating and the cord is too small.  There is one problem that is you are using an old type NEMA 10(two hots and neutral, no ground) circuit which is unsafe to you.  This is highly recommended to be changed to a four wire circuit with ground.  If your range uses ground and no neutral you are good with three wire.  NEMA 10 plugs have three flat prongs(bad), If using ground two flat prongs and a round one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got a call (have to do some work sometimes) and didn't finish posting my Answer before the question was closed due to needing more details (which is correct). A 3-prong connection **usually** means "hot/hot/neutral" and no ground. Which is **DANGEROUS**. So before going any farther we need to find out whether the **new** range uses neutral or not. **Make/model # of new range, please.** Then I can provide a complete answer (or find a duplicate for it) which will either be "Take the time now to replace the 3 with 4" or "Hardwire" or "Replace 3 with no ground with instead 3 with

Comment: no neutral but with ground". Don't know yet. But please, don't get all upset about the cord. An appliance cord is typically $15 - $40 depending on brand, length, type. I am sure that is a *tiny* fraction of the total cost of the range.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few reasons appliance stores do this. They don't want to accept liability for the condition of your old cord. Ranges are often twenty years old or older when they are replaced. They don't want to show up and find out that the cord on your range is cracked, or melted, or was poorly connected and burned, or really that there is anything wrong with it. They don't want to show up and find out you don't have a cord. So by default they suggest a new cord.

Is it strictly needed? No. It may be required if you want to use their installation services though, so if you want them to do the install, you're buying a new cord. If you are doing your own installation and the current cord is in good condition, you can reuse it.